# Predefine Magazine Style Layouts

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, css, mysql

I want my customer to be able to create a post by select between a significant number of magazine style layouts (possibly generated by me). Typically, they would have a number of images and pick a layout suitable for that number of images (or more). Perhaps one large image and two smaller with a block of text between them, or a 3x3 grid, or a 2x4 grid etc.

**Is there any way to achieve this, or is this a no-no in WordPress?**

I'm a complete WordPress amateur, just toying around with it right now. But I have good knowledge of MySQL, PHP and CSS, and considered writing everything myself, but thought it would be a time saver to use this framework. But before digging too deep I'd like to know it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a couple known plugins. **TYPES and VIEWS**, by [wp-types.com](http://wp-types.com/). Please keep in mind that I am in no way, shape, or form affiliated with these plugins or plugin authors. Also, please note, the TYPES plugin is free, and the VIEWS plugin is premium. You will not be able to receive support for premium WordPress plugins on WordPress Stack Exchange, however, the developers of TYPES and VIEWS provide [support](http://wp-types.com/forums/) for their premium plugins.

---

**Types and Views** help you build WordPress sites faster and better. Customize editing, create templates and craft queries right from the WordPress admin.

Types and Views let you create whatever you want, bug-free, simple and fast.

- Define your own content types and customize edit screens
- Load content from the database and display it any way you choose
- Create page templates using the visual editor

Extra Links
 - [Quickies – 5 minute tutorials on the very basic](http://wp-types.com/learn/)
 - [Documentation](http://wp-types.com/documentation/)
 - [Showcase](http://wp-types.com/showcase/)

Types and Views are two WordPress plugins that work in perfect harmony, together, enabling rapid development of WordPress sites.

Types includes everything a web developer needs to customize the WordPress admin. The base [Types plugin](http://wp-types.com/home/types-manage-post-types-taxonomy-and-custom-fields/) includes:

- Custom post types management
- Custom fields management
- Post relationship management

[Views plugin](http://wp-types.com/home/views-create-elegant-displays-for-your-content/) loads content from the database and displays it. You can create single-page templates and content listing quickly and easily, all from within the WordPress admin.

Views makes it easy to create content lists, tables, grids, sliders. It works with any theme and lets you build the exact functionality that your sites need.